# How to change the background color of button in ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

I am developing an application where I need to design the two button and when I have dragged the button on the story board they looks perfect but when I run the app then there is background color (blue) by default so can you  please help e out.

Thanks in advance
Here you can see the background color is blue but I need it to be transparent of white color so what can I do for it ?

[image]

Comment: Have you try `buttton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]`

Comment: Also show some code and storyboard screen.

Comment: Thanks Nirav this worked for me